# How to normalize if variance is zero?

Tags: variance, z-score

How do I normalize a dataset to z-scores is some features have variance zero? Is throwing them away beforehand the only solution?

Comment: What's the intended purpose of normalization?

Comment: @whuber to feed it to PCA. Also in Bayesian class they told us it is often used nearly without reason.

Comment: Assuming the PCA is based on centered values, normalizing it won't change a thing: it's constant, and so will effectively disappear.  If you don't center the values, then the results of the PCA will arbitrarily depend on how you rescale this variable.  We have many threads about PCA and how to choose variables for it: see [tag:pca].

Comment: If the variance of a feature is zero, it means that it has exactly the same value in all samples. I'm not aware of any analysis that benefits from a completely constant feature. I'd suggest throwing it away!

Comment: Agree with Djib2011. Constant variables do not add any extra information in classification or prediction. I would however note in your analysis that you removed the variable and what your justification is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling them all 0 so their distribution is a degenerate normal with mean 0 and variance 0 (point mass at 0) makes sense to me. As the comments note, however, a constant variable gives no separation in your regression, so you can discard that variable. Do note why you’ve excluded the variable so you have a rebuttal when your reviewer, professor, or boss critiques your model that has omitted data, however.

**EDIT**

If you elect to run PCA on variables that are not centered, your results will be different with the constant variables included and when they are excluded.

Comment: When the PCA does not center the variables, the results will differ depending on whether the constant variables are included or not.  This deserves comment.

Comment: @Dave: Could you augment this answer in accordance with the comment by whuber?